# Connecting Fragmented regions in an image using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

Hi i am trying to detect a person. to do this i subtract background from foreground to get a foreground mask. I multiply the output with the foreground image to get back the person. The problem here is that i sometimes get fragmented mask. Is there a way i can connect the fragments together to get a proper image? I use GMM(Gaussian Mixture Model) to subtract the background.

[image: The picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [mathematical morphology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology). Off the top of my head, I would try to apply the following operations, on the mask, in that order:

1. Apply a dilation using a vertical kernel (i.e., structuring element), whose dimensions would be more or less those of a standing human being. The goal here is to connect the pixels vertically.
2. Then apply an erosion filter, to get back to a more realistic shape.
3. Finally, use the mask the same way you did.

Have a look at the Matlab documentation about dilation and erosion morphological operations, [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/morphology-fundamentals-dilation-and-erosion.html).

Comment: Hi!!! Thanks for the reply.Applying  dilation and erosion was my first approach too. The problem with that is that it merges many other fragments.
my code:
se = strel('line',5,90);        
dilateddBW = imdilate(BW,se);

Comment: What other fragments, do you mean noise? With Mixture of Gaussian any noise should be eliminated. OK then, if noise is the problem, first apply an erosion filter, then dilate (both operation with the same kernel, this operation is actually called Opening). This way you will get rid of the noise. Do you need to get the exact shape? In most application having the center is enough, as long as you have a blog to follow.

Comment: I meant, a blob to follow, not a blog :-)

Comment: Applying erosion first makes me loose the bottom portion all together in some other images. your suggestion was helpful in very limited cases. I am working with gait so legs are quite important. Thanks.

Comment: Then you will probably have to use machine learning. Have a look at this: http://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_current_state_of_the_art_methods_tracking_human_detection_and_segmentation_in_static_images